# (.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `TextOutA@20'

Tags: c++, windows, textout

I've Been trying to fix this code for days now. When I try to compile `main.cpp` It gives me the error `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\cckKRlpR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to TextOutA@20'`. I've also tried including gdi32.lib and lgdi32 but It still gives me the error. If you know how to solve this problem please tell me. Here's The source code btw:

```
// main.cpp
// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wingdi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("Hello, World");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Hello, World App");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
   HINSTANCE hInstance,
   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
   int       nCmdShow
)
{
   WNDCLASSEX wcex;

   wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
   wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
   wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
   wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
   wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
   wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
   wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
   wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
   wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
   wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
   wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
   wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

   if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
   {
      MessageBox(NULL, "Call to RegisterClassEx failed!", "Hello, World App", MB_OK);

      return 1;
   }

   // Store instance handle in our global variable
   hInst = hInstance;

   // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
   // szWindowClass: the name of the application
   // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
   // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
   // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
   // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
   // NULL: the parent of this window
   // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
   // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
   // NULL: not used in this application
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
      szWindowClass,
      szTitle,
      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
      500, 100,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      hInstance,
      NULL
   );

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      MessageBox(NULL, "Call to RegisterClassEx failed!", "Windows Desktop Guided Tour", MB_OK);

      return 1;
   }

   // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
   // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
   // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
   ShowWindow(hWnd,
      nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   // Main message loop:
   MSG msg;
   while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
   {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }

   return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;
   HDC hdc;
   TCHAR greeting[] = ("Hello, World");

   switch (message)
   {
   case WM_PAINT:
      hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

      
      TextOut(hdc,
         5, 5,
         greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
      // End application-specific layout section.

      EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
      break;
   case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
   default:
      return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
      break;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you build? How exactly are you specifying libraries?

Comment: Are you getting a linker warning about not being able to find or link `gdi32.lib`? Show the actual output.

Comment: No Blindy I am not getting a linker warning. I also am compiling with mingw

Comment: Does MingW understand/implement `#pragma comment(lib...)` ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your actual, exact compilation/linking command(s).

Comment: What compiler are you using? `TextOutA@20` doesn't look like the name decoration for any of Microsoft's calling conventions.

Comment: Adrian Mole, I am assuming that MingW understands it. But I'm not entirely sure. IInspectable I Use MingW and g++ to compile my programs.

Comment: This is Windows code. Using anything but Microsoft's compiler is a painful experience. Is there a specific reason you aren't using Microsoft's compiler?

Comment: No, not really. I just prefer what I use.

Comment: A corollary of your preference is having to deal with unofficial and hopelessly outdated SDKs.

Comment: So I'm using an outdated SDK?

Comment: Sure, but that's not causing your issues. The GDI is probably as old as Windows.

Comment: Think of it this way: The same organization that provides the Visual Studio development tools also provides the operating system you're writing for. This allows them to tune things a lot better than GCC, which supports a huge umbrella of platforms and, as a result, generally needs to support the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you so much

Comment: @noobbit Not the error here, but ... 1) The top code comment says `// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE`, while the reference to `TextOutA` suggests that you are not. 2) `TCHAR greeting[] = ("Hello, World");` Mixing generic text macros like `TCHAR` and plain C strings like `"Hello, World"` is a problem waiting to happen.